# Castle ActiveRecord: What's the easiest way to see the SQL?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to get Castle ActiveRecord to show me the SQL it generates.  The various blogs I've found on this give two alternatives:

(1) **Use the NHibernate "show_sql" setting**.  The trouble is, I'm using programmatic configuration, like this.

```
var config = XmlConfigurationSource.Build(
    DatabaseType.MsSqlServer2008, Settings.Default.StationManagerDbConnectionString);
config.IsRunningInWebApp = isRunningInWebApp;
config.PluralizeTableNames = true;
var modelAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(OneOfMyClasses));
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(modelAssembly, config);
```

With programmatic configuration, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify "show_sql".

(2) **Use log4net**.  But leaving aside what a pain log4net is to get working, I haven't found a way to get *just* the SQL.  I get gobs and gobs of debug data, of which the SQL statements are just a small part.

So: Is there some way I can keep my programmatic configuration of Castle ActiveRecord but also get NHibernate to output just the SQL?

EDIT: Here's what I got to work with log4net.  But in the first two pages of my web app, this spits out over 14,000 lines in the Debug window.  How do I change this code to get only the SQL?

```
var appender = new log4net.Appender.DebugAppender
{
    Layout = new log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout(),
    Name = "NHibernate.SQL",
    Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Debug
};
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just separate out the sql by utilizing the **NHibernate.SQL** logger.

Example config:

```
<log4net>
<!-- This is a default logger that nhibernate uses to push out all the SQL statements to-->
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSQLLog"/>
</logger>

<!-- This is a default logger that nhibernate uses to push out all the debugging type information to-->
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateFileLog"/>
</logger>

<appender name="NHibernateFileLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs/nhibernate.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="NHibernateSQLLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs/nhibernate_sql.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
  </layout>
 </appender>
 </log4net>
```

**Edit:**

```
var filter = new log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter();
filter.LoggerToMatch = "NHibernate.SQL";
filter.AcceptOnMatch = true;

var filterDeny = new log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter();

var appender = new log4net.Appender.DebugAppender
{
    Layout = new log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout(),
    Name = "NHibernate.SQL",
    Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Debug
};

appender.AddFilter(filter);
appender.AddFilter(filterDeny);
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
```

Comment: see my edit.  Is there any easy way to modify the log4net configuration code I'm using to output just the SQL?

Comment: @Kyralessa, Look at my edit.  This code is untested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

The very best tool for the task is the NHibernate Profiler ( http://nhprof.com/ ).
It's a commercial application but you get 30 days free trial.

Comment: OK, just for grins, I tried it.  It asks me to register for a 30-day trial.  So I put in my name and e-mail address and hit "Start trial".  It brings up a new, empty window for a few seconds, then shuts down for no apparent reason.  Color me unimpressed.

Comment: Never had any problem with the installation process, even so, this is still one of the most important tools of the trade when you work intensively with NH.

Comment: Then when I ran it, there was no obvious way to get started.  Then after I found *that* on the NHProf site, I ran my app, and NHProf just kept churning away and locked up.  I finally had to End Task on it.  It seems as if it would be really useful, but out-of-the-box usability could use some improvement.